# How to describe all Security Group in which inbound rule's source is not "sg-12345678"

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

Using AWS CLI, i can list all Security Group which has inbound rule like this:

```
Type  Protocol   Port Range Source           Description
MYSQL   TCP          3306    sg-12345678      From App
```

With a command line

```
aws ec2 describe-security-groups --filters Name=ip-permission.group-id,Values=sg-12345678 --query "SecurityGroups[*].{Name:GroupName}"
```

However, my intention is to find all SG that doesn't have sg-12345678 as a source in inbound rule.

How can i achieve this?

Comment: You would need to write a program (eg in Python) that grabs a list of all security groups, then looks at the rules in each security group to identify the ones with/without a certain security group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example using `--query`, needs further parsing with jq or any other command line tools.

```
aws ec2 describe-security-groups --query "SecurityGroups[*].{name:GroupName,secid:GroupId,sourceid:IpPermissions[*].UserIdGroupPairs[?GroupId!='sg-1234567']}"
```

Comment: I agree that the query/jq method is a good solution.  The code provided returns all of my security groups including ones with the negated GroupId